# Отрисовка сетки

Tags: c#, gdi, winforms

Встал вопрос о написании собственного контрола(наследовал от Panel). После отрисовки, когда изменяешь размеры формы получается фигня что-то вроде

[image: Сетка]

Догадываюсь, что нужно использовать Invalidate. Помогает, но частично... Сетка начинает мерцать. DoubleBuffered не помогает.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Rectangle r = e.ClipRectangle;
        var p = Pens.Gray;
        //Draw columns
        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
            g.DrawLine(p, r.X + i * ColunmWidth, r.Y, r.X + i * ColunmWidth, r.Y + r.Height);
        for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
            g.DrawLine(p, r.X, r.Y + i * RowHeight, r.X + r.Width, r.Y + i * RowHeight);
    }
```

Comment: > DoubleBuffered не помогает

Помогает, вы просто его не умеете использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо Rectangle r = e.ClipRectangle; надо Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;
Решил расширить ответ...
e.ClipRectangle дает только ту область, которая подверглась изменению, следовательно Вы рисуете не в полном окне, а только в области изменения. Отсюда и артефакты.